# Getting Facebook movie suggestions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to retrieve movie suggestions on Facebook using Graph API? Is there any way to get the list?
I tried getting from "movies" in graph API but I don't see any option available to retrieve. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using graph api as of right now, unfortunately.  The closest thing is with a user token, grabbing a list of movies that the user has liked.  /userid/movies.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/movies